# golang recover return value syntax

Tags: go

I'm trying to understand how to recover from panic situation. Normally, something like this will do:

```
 if r := recover(); r != nil {
    fmt.Println("Recovered in f", r)
 }
```

I can understand those much. But I've seen code snippet like the following:

```
 if r, ok := recover().(error); ok {
    fmt.Println("Recovered in f", r)
 }
```

What's the `.(error)` part doing?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It is a **[type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions)** which check if the [error recovered](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#recover) is of a certain type.

It that type assertion fails, that causes a run-time error that continues the stack unwinding as though nothing had interrupted it.

This is useful when you define a local `MyError` type for error, and you want to recover only from that type.

You can see an example in "[Error handling and Go](http://blog.golang.org/error-handling-and-go)"

> Client code can test for a net.Error with a type assertion and then distinguish transient network errors from permanent ones.
>
> For instance, a web crawler might:
>
> - sleep and retry when it encounters a temporary error
> - and give up otherwise.

```
if nerr, ok := err.(net.Error); ok && nerr.Temporary() {
    time.Sleep(1e9)
    continue
}
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

---

If you have *several* types of error you want to recover, you can use a type switch is in "[Golang: returning from defer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19934989/6309)"

```
defer func() {
    if r := recover(); r != nil {
        fmt.Println("Recovered in f", r)
        // find out exactly what the error was and set err
        switch x := r.(type) {
        case string:
            err = errors.New(x)
        case error:
            err = x
        default:
            // Fallback err (per specs, error strings should be lowercase w/o punctuation
            err = errors.New("unknown panic")
        }
        // invalidate rep
        rep = nil
        // return the modified err and rep
    }
}()
```